# How to implement ui-grid with trailing infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, angular-ui-grid

I have a requirement, to add infinite scroll to my ui-grid component. Following [this](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll) tutorial I have successfully implemented my scrolling grid, but when it comes to performance, the results do not suit my requirements, so I need to add trailing to this implementation, meaning I need to load more data the I display on the grid.

e.g. call the backend for 100 elements and display in one scroll only 20, in this way I limit the number of calls to the backend.

So how is the best way of doing this using this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tune you performance by changing infiniteScrollRowsFromEnd in gridOptions.
This way you choose how far from the bottom new data should be requested. Then again the amount of rows to download is chosen by you.

If you choose a small number for the former and a big one for the latter you will have few calls to your service but the user may experience some waiting.